# How do I build a world for a line follower bot in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, line-following

I am just starting off in robotics with my own little pet project: a line follower using openCV. However, I have no idea how to create a world in Gazebo for the bot. I went through the official Gazebo tutorials, however there doesn't seem to be stuff that can help me with this.

I intend to build a plane which will be the floor of the room and "paint" a line on it for the bot to follow. I know many pre-made models exist, but I would like to try it out on my own. How can I achieve this? Can Blender be used to create such a room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the high level you're going to add a texture to the ground plane for the simplest approach. There's a [gazebo tutorial on adding color and textures](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=color_model). The coloring of the line is a texture. There's also a section on [Textures in the model Appearance Tutorial Gazebo Tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i2)

There are many different tools that you can use to create the textures and models with textures. Blender is a commonly used tool, but you can use any 3D drawing tool.

However I'd suggest looking for projects who have already done this that you can play with. A good way to learn how to work with things is to start with an existing model and modify it instead of trying to start from scratch at first.

A quick search finds several projects with line follower worlds already implemented.

- https://github.com/sudrag/line_follower_turtlebot
- http://edu.gaitech.hk/turtlebot/line-follower.html
- https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/111138/tot.pdf

Comment: I thought starting from scratch would give me a better understanding of a wide array of topics. But yeah, modifying existing worlds sounds better. Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer!